# pasting with overwrite by motion in vim

Tags: vim

Consider the following, frequent situation.

```
do_something("argument to use");
do_something_else("here I want the same argument es above");
```

I have copied the second line from somewhere else. But it has the wrong argument. I want to have it the same argument as the line above. So I move up there to the `a` of `argument…` and press in normal mode `yt"` (=**y**ank **t**ill **"**). This copies everything within and excluding the quotes. Then I move one line down to the `h` of `here…` where I want to replace everything within these quotes with what I have just copied, something like `rt"` (=**r**eplace **t**ill **"**) but `r` is already used to replace a single character. Is that possible?

PS: I know in this case I could just copy the first line and add the `_else` to `do_something`. But this is just an example and I somehow can't believe there is no way to do it like I described in vim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using visual mode. When your cursor is on the `h`, simply press:

```
vt"p
```

- `v` enables visual mode.
- `t"` will move your cursor to right before the `"` and select everything on its way.
- `p` will paste over the selected text.

Comment: Ah okay, I usually try to avoid visual mode but here it comes in handy thanks!

Comment: No problem! Yeah, visual mode is not my favorite either, but it has some powerful features.

Answer (score 3):

I need this so often, I wrote a plugin to simplify and allow maximum speed: [ReplaceWithRegister](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2703).

This plugin offers a two-in-one `gr` command that replaces text covered by a {motion} / text object, entire line(s) or the current selection with the contents of a register; the old text is deleted into the black-hole register, i.e. it's gone. It transparently handles many corner cases and allows for a quick repeat via the standard `.` command. Should you not like it, its page has links to alternatives.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look!

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the visual mode solution, you could use the black hole register to delete the text on the second line before pasting the correct version.

```
"_di"P
```

- `"_di"` delete between the `""` (same as `"_dt"` if you are at the start of the quote)
- `P` the above leaves the cursor over the closing `"` so paste the text before the cursor.

Comment: This is also the more vim-like way, but I think using visual mode in this scenario is easier to comprehend and a little easier to hit.

Comment: Cool. I didn't know about the "inner" stuff. Thanks! But as Sander says, his version is easier.

Comment: No worries. It's whatever is most useful at the time. There is also `a` as a complement to `i` that includes the surrounding character. eg `da"` would delete the `"` as well as the text between them.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use `c{motion}` and then in insert mode use `CTRL-R0` to paste the last yanked content.

```
ci"<C-R>0
```

- `ci"` deletes between `""` and then goes to inesrt mode
- `<C-R>{register}` will paste the content content in register `{register}` in the current cursur position in insert mode, and the 0 register contains the result of the most recent yank command (`:h "0`).

i've found this solution easier to hit than `"_di"P`, while still enabling pasting multiple times.